# Google Maps Marker Clusterer Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have a map with 5 markers with 4 of them being in Jacksonville, FL and 1 in West Palm Beach, FL. I want the 4 markers to be clustered in the initialized zoom level. When zoomed in to level 15 in Jacksonville, I want the cluster to show the 4 markers separately.

[image]

So far, this code hasn't worked for me:

```
echo "
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var florida =  new google.maps.LatLng(28.4811689,-81.36875);

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 6,
  center: florida
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_map_0'), mapOptions);

var marker_icon_for_sale = '".get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/images/house-marker-for-sale.png';
var marker_icon_sold = '".get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/images/house-marker-sold.png';
var marker_icon_hq = '".get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/images/star-icon.png';

var infowindow;

var markers = [];

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

";

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $thumbnail_object = get_post($thumbnail_id);
}

echo "
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '".urlencode(get_the_title())."'}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        title: '".get_the_title()."',
        draggable: false,
        icon: ".(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hq') ? "marker_icon_hq" : (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sold') ? "marker_icon_sold" : "marker_icon_for_sale"))."
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '".(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ? "<img width=\"100\" height=\"100\" src=\"".$thumbnail_object->guid."\" style=\"float: left;\">" : "")."<div style=\"width: 125px; padding: 5px; float: right;\"><b>Status:</b> ".(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sold') ? 'Sold' : 'For Sale')."<br> ".get_the_title()."<br><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">Project Info</a></div>'
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
  }
});

";

endwhile;
echo "

var mcOptions = {gridSize: 20, maxZoom: 15};
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
});

";
```

When I check the debugger, I get no errors or warnings. Why is this code not working?

Comment: Because the geocoder is asynchronous.  When you load the markers array into the MarkerCluster, it is empty, none of the geocoding results have come back.  I suggest you initialize the MarkerCluster before the geocode calls, then add each marker to the clusterer when the callback function runs.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks, that did the trick. Never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous. When you load the markers array into the MarkerCluster, it is empty, none of the geocoding results have come back. I suggest you initialize the MarkerCluster before the geocode calls, then add each marker to the clusterer when the callback function runs.